# determining if a status update is a retweet using api 1.1

Tags: json, api, twitter

I want a simple, robust way to identify retweets in a hashtag search using twitter api 1.1.

For example, if I send the following request with the proper authentication:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23stackoverflow
```

I'll get the last 15 tweets tagged with #stackoverflow.

It looks like only retweeted status updates have the 'retweet_status' property. Is checking to see if the tweet has a 'retweet_status' property a reliable way to determine if it is a retweet?

'retweet' and 'retweet_count' don't give me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds rather like you've answered your own question. `retweeted_status` is present when the retweeter has used Twitter's *official* Retweet function.

However people still to the old style `RT: <quote>` approach which won't give you any solid data bindings in the data returned from the API. The only way to handle these is to compare the text and see if the original text is contained. If they've modified the text then you're stuck, but then if they've modified the text then technically it's not a Retweet - it's just plagiarism ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've come to realize there is no one size fits all solution, but filtering on RT: <quote> might be the best general option. Of course the use of MT adds another set of edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share my solution...

```
if (eventMsg.retweeted_status == null) {
  //run code
}
```